# Flink ProcessFunction onTimer first event LONG.MIN_VALUE

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I am having a use case: stepA -> stepB -> stepC ...   Now I need to use Flink processfunction to monitor the track.  for example, once stepA comes in, I set up a timer 10s after A, and when 10s has passed, that timer is triggered, and we check our state to see if stepB has showed up. But here is the problem I have: I am using event-time with AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks. But when I print the context.timeservice().currentwatermark() in stepA, it shows LONG.MIN_VALUE.    And the watermark of stepB is A's timestamp. I know this is due to

```
  public long extractTimestamp(
      MyEvent event, long previousElementTimestamp) {
      return event.getTimeStamp();
  }
  
  public Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(
      MyEvent event, long extractedTimestamp) {
    return new Watermark(extractedTimestamp);
  }
```

But what else can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way that Flink applies watermarking is that watermarks follow the events that were used as evidence for creating the watermark. Thus the current watermark will be LONG.MIN_VALUE during the processing of the first event, after which the watermark will be advanced.

From what you've shared, it isn't clear why this is a problem for your application.

By the way, your watermark generator is assuming that your events are strictly in order, by timestamp. Is that actually true?